# Import a varible's value from remote machine to local python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, python-import

I have python script **first.py** running on **machine A** which generates the value of variable **device_name = A**. I would like get the value of **device_name = A** to **machine B**  & use that for manipulation in **clean.py** ( which is running on **machine B**)

I have added the below **from** statement & tried to run clean.py from **machine B** getting below error.

**from A import device_name**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clean.py", line 4, in <module>
    from first.py import device_name
ImportError: No module named 'first.py'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.py` extension should not be part of the argument to `import`. You are importing a *module,* not a file name.

(In the trivial case, they correspond 1:1, but the ability to support nontrivial cases is the reason this is more complex than that.)